# Json on Android

Tags: android

Anybody can give me a Android tutorial for parsing Json data which is located in web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand German, this is great:

http://andforge.net/2010/serverkommunikation-android-rest-json/

And during my implementation work, I also used this useful source:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/?ca=drs-

Answer (score 2):

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

More generally:
http://www.google.com/search?q=android+json+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a